# C process printing twice after fork() even though it's inside the parent process and I flush stdout

Tags: c, linux, printf, buffer, shared-memory

I'm working on a C project for school that involves using shared memory but I can't seem to figure out why the parent process is printing the results twice after the fork. I flush the stdout after the print, but it still prints twice.

Heres my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

/* Defining system macros to avoid magic numbers */
#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0
#define MEM_SIZE sizeof(collatz_data)
#define NAME "OS"
#define SEQ_SIZE 50

/* A data struct that will be put into the shared memory to store our values */
typedef struct {
    int starting_number;
    int sequence[SEQ_SIZE];
    int seq_count;
    int is_finished;
} collatz_data;

/* Function for calculating the collatz formula */
int calculate_collatz(int n) {
    return (n % 2 == 0) ?  (n / 2) : (3 * n + 1);
}

/* Shared memory passing project main run loop */
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    
    int shm_fd;
    pid_t pid;
    collatz_data *shared_memory;
    
    /* Requirement 1: Check to see if the number passed on the command line is positive */
    if (argv[1] <= 0) {
        printf("The number you entered was not positive.\n Exiting program...\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    
    /* Getting the number from the command line using atoi function to turn character into int */
    int number = atoi(argv[1]);
    
    printf("\n");
    
    /* Create the shared memeory segment & configure it's size*/
    shm_fd = shm_open(NAME, O_CREAT | O_RDWR, 0666);
    ftruncate(shm_fd, MEM_SIZE);
    
    /* Map the shaerd memory segment to this address space */
    shared_memory = mmap(0, MEM_SIZE, PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, shm_fd, 0);
    
    /* Check to see that our shared memory segment was mapped correctly */
    if (shared_memory == MAP_FAILED) {
        printf("Map Failed\n");
        return -1;
    }
    
    
    /* Fork the current process and create a child */
    fflush(stdout);
    pid = fork();

      /* Check if the fork failed */
      if ((pid=fork()) == -1) {
          perror("Fork Failed");
          
          /* Kill the program */
          exit(1);
      }

     // Child
     else if (pid == 0) {

         int i = 0;
         int n = shared_memory->starting_number;
         
         /* Make the first number in the sequence the number from the command line */
         shared_memory->sequence[i++] = n;
         
         /* Calculate the collatz sequence by storing the numbers in our shared memory sequence */
         while (n != 1 && i < SEQ_SIZE) {
             n = calculate_collatz(n);
             shared_memory->sequence[i++] = n; // Store the next number
         }
         
         /* Store the size of our sequence so the parent can loop over this number later to print it out*/
         shared_memory->seq_count = i;

         // Kill the child process
         exit(0);
     }
      
      // Parent
         else if (pid > 0) {
             
             /* Requirement 2: Pass the input from the command line to the child process */
             shared_memory->starting_number = number;
             
             /* Requirement 4: Inoviking wait will the child calculates the sequence */
             wait(NULL);
             
             printf("Collatz Sequence for number (%d): \n", number);

             /* Requirement 5: Print out collatz results generated by the child */
             for (int i = 0; i < shared_memory->seq_count; i++) {
                 printf("%d ", shared_memory->sequence[i]);
             }
             printf("\n");
             fflush(stdout);
             
             exit(0);
         }
    
     /* Remove the shared memory object */
     shm_unlink(NAME);

    return 0;
}
```

The output should be:

**Collatz Sequence for number (99):
99 298 149 448 224 112 56 28 14 7 22 11 34 17 52 26 13 40 20 10 5 16 8 4 2 1**

But for some reason that entire thing gets printed twice. Any ideas of what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: Your entire logic is inside a `do {} while`, are you sure that the body is only executed once? Because from the output it doesn't look like so.

Comment: @Marco_Bonelli Yes. I removed the do while and it still prints twice

Comment: I'm not an expert in Collatz Sequences, but the internal `while (n != 1 && i < SEQ_SIZE) {` *can* exit without having set `is_finished` to `1`, so you can get a second cycle to start.

Comment: You should post the actual code, possibly in the form of a [mre], otherwise it's only harder to answer this.

Comment: @Marco_Bonelli I've edited the code to remove the do{} while but I mean the entire code minus preprocessor statements is less than 100 lines, and its the bare minimum thats needed to reproduce the problem. Not sure what else can really be done.

Comment: This may seem a trivial point, but error messages belong on stderr.  If you ever write `printf("...error...")`, please consider instead using `fprintf(stderr, " ...error...")`.  This will help to prevent the untimely death of millions of kittens.

Comment: Will do! Thanks for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured this one out.

Changed this:

```
if ((pid=fork()) == -1) {
      perror("Fork Failed");
      
      /* Kill the program */
      exit(1);
  }
```

To This:

```
if (pid == -1) {
      perror("Fork Failed");
      
      /* Kill the program */
      exit(1);
 }
```

Turns out I had an entire other process running this exact same code. After removing that the problem was solved.